# How to format the proc means results?

Tags: sas

```
proc mean data =table A  mean;
var interestRate;
run;
```

The variable interest rate is already in percentage format in table A. But the proc means doesn't return the results in percentage.
How to get the mean interst rate in percentage format when doing the proc means?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any way to format the output directly.  You can use a `format` statement to change how the data would be formatted in an `output` dataset, and then use `PROC REPORT` or similar to produce output similar to `PROC MEANS` output.  You might also consider `PROC TABULATE` if it's a fairly simple table.